# Where can I find how to do data analysis for a magnetic hysteresis loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, data-analysis

I am given a data set that has a hysteresis loop but there's a diamagnetic signal that I understand needs to be subtracted, but I don't know the how this is done. I remember finding the slope of the loop at the flat ends and using this in some way but that's how far my memory serves me.

Comment: This question isn't clear. Can you explain what you want to know?  Measuring a hysteresis loop just involves sweeping the input from min to max and max to min while recording the output, so you must have something going on that isn't clear from your question.

Comment: If I plot the data, the hysteresis loop will not have flat ends, the ends are tilted a bit because of a diamagnetic contribution. The purpose of the subtraction is to have the ends of the hysteresis loop to be horizontally flat. I don't know how to do this subtraction and I'd like for someone to help me with this preferably by pointing me to a detailed reference.

Comment: The ends are tilted?  Is this an issue of current saturation?  Can you post a graph of what you're talking about and perhaps a block diagram of what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can replace the hysteresis data with either smooth or piecewise-linear model (see for example “An improved parametric model for hysteresis loop approximation”, R. V. Lapshin, Review of Scientific Instruments, vol. 91, iss. 6, no. 065106, 31 pp., 2020, DOI: 10.1063/5.0012931). You can fit the data simply by eye or by using the least-mean squares approach (eye-fitting will provide results suitable for the most of practical cases). After that you can manipulate with your curves as needed (in particular, substract the curves).

Comment: For the hysteresis loop there is also this model: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110283/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60194/226902. Alternatively: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110236/226902