# Hysteresis Curve and how to implement it using Preisach model or other models

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, computational-physics

As a homework I need to draw a hysteresis curve (preferably an interactive one) using Matlab or any other programming language. The problem is I have trouble finding a good algorithm to do so. I need something that can be implemented easily and in a systematic way. [The Preisach model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preisach_model_of_hysteresis) seems to be the best way, but I don't really get it. Can you suggest a good model/algorithm or explain Preisach model for me?  The main problem that I have with Preisach model is that I don't understand how exactly $\mu$ and other magnetic properties affect $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in this model.

Comment: See http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/076/014/ecp12076014.pdf. Beside Preisach's model there is also Tellinen's hysteresis discussed there. Tellinen's approach is the simpliest that I know of.