# Jiles-Atherton model of hysteresis

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In my quest for finding a good algorithm to draw hysteresis curve,I have found Jiles-Atherton model which seems to be a rather new model. But I have trouble understanding some of the variables/constants that are used in the formulation.There seems to be a rather similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60194/equation-describing-magnetic-hysteresis). What I have trouble understanding is that what are Mirr and Man? And how is it possible that M is defined using Mirr and Man, and yet in the definition of Man we use M ?

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110236/2451

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my answer to the question you referenced; maybe the nature of the various components will now be clearer.

The model equations are indeed challenging.  One can substitute for $M$ in the equation for $M_{an}$, leaving a pair of [simultaneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_equations) equations, one [transcendental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) (for $M_{an}$) and one [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation) (for $M_{irr}$).

$$ M_{an} = M_s \left[\coth\left(\frac{H+ \alpha (cM_{an}+(1-c)M_{irr})}{A}- \frac{A}{H+\alpha (cM_{an}+(1-c)M_{irr})} \right)  \right] $$

$$ \frac{dM_{irr}}{dH} = \frac{M_{an} - M_{irr}}{k \delta - \alpha (M_{an}- M_{irr})} $$

After solving for $M_{an}$ and $M_{irr}$, $M=cM_{an}+(1-c)M_{irr}$ can be determined.

As far as I know, numerical methods are required.